# Using v-radio inside v-tab

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'd like to use `v-radio` inside `v-tab` and select it when the tab choiced
But the problem is I don't know how to select single `v-radio` without `v-radio-group` because I have v-for and my `v-tabs` styles break with it
I tried use v-model in `v-radio` but it haven't any effect for `v-radio` select

**UPD**: a link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/somethinglike/pen/QWQqVNV) where you can see the problem if you'll uncomment v-radio-group lines

Comment: You want the user to only select one radio between all pages ?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly try to wrap `v-tabs` with `v-radio-group`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      selectedFilterTypeIndex: 0
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.v-input--selection-controls.v-input {
  flex: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-card>
            <v-toolbar tile  dense color="blue-grey darken-2">
            <template v-slot:extension>
                <v-radio-group grow v-model="selectedFilterTypeIndex">
                    <v-tabs grow dark   background-color="transparent"
                        slider-size="3" slider-color="yellow"
                        v-model="selectedFilterTypeIndex"
                    >
                        <v-tab :key="index" v-for="(name, index) in ['item1', 'item2']">
                            <v-radio :label="name" :value="index"   />
                        </v-tab>
                    </v-tabs>
                </v-radio-group>
            </template>
        </v-toolbar>
        </v-card>
    </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I had a mistake. I did't write about coverage of my tabs. Could you look at my codepen? If you will uncomment v-radio-group lines you can see the wrong style. [codepen](https://codepen.io/somethinglike/pen/QWQqVNV)